# Linear Algebra Problem - Ph.D exam

Tags: linear-algebra

I stole this problem from a Ph.D exam from another university.

> Let $V$ be a real vector space and let $T: V \to \mathbb{R}$ be a linear transformation. Suppose $(v_1, \dots, v_n)$ is a bssis for $\ker(T)$. Suppose $v \in V, v \neq 0$ is *not* in $\ker T$. Prove that $(v, v_1, \dots, v_n)$ is a basis for $V$.

Here is some scratch work I wrote.

$T(dv + a_1v_1 + \dots + a_nv_n) = T(dv) + 0 = dT(v)$

Now I have also observed that $\beta = (v, v_1, \dots, v_n)$ is linearly independent in $V$. I am not sure if I am allowed to assume $V$ is finite dimensional. If it is, I can use a theorem to extend $\beta$ to a basis. Otherwise, I am stuck

**EDIT** I just noticed the problem tells me that $\beta$ has $n + 1$ vectors, so maybe i am allowed to?

Comment: Which university does Ph.D. exams? And ones like this?

Comment: No it's taken from a comprehensive pure math exam.

Comment: Looks like an "entry-level" qualifying exam problem. This is just rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: It probably is, because a simple recursive problem follows right after this one...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $u \in V$.  We want to show that $u$ is in the subspace generated by $\ker T$ and $v$.  Because $Tv$ is a nonzero real number, it spans $\mathbb{R}$ and so we have $Tu = \alpha Tv$ for some real number $\alpha$.  Therefore $u - \alpha v \in \ker T$, so $u$ is the sum of $\alpha v$ and a vector in $\ker T$ as desired.

Comment: Why does $V = \ker T \oplus v$?

Comment: @sidht You showed that $(v,v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ is linearly independent, so it remains to show that it spans $V$, right?

Comment: Right, so can't I use a well-known linear algebra theorem to finish the job? I have also noticed the list is finite

Comment: @sidht Maybe, but I don't see why that would be preferable.  Also, note that the argument in my answer does need the assumption that $V$ is finite-dimensional, nor even that $\ker T$ is finite-dimensional.

Comment: Okay, your proof is better, but am I wrong? I know i kinda "cheated" here...

Comment: @sidht You are wondering if you are allowed to assume that $V$ is finite-dimensional?  To me it's not obvious that this follows from the kernel being finite-dimensional unless you use some kind of argument like I did.  And the version of the rank-nullity theorem that I know is stated only for finite-dimensional spaces.  But would be easier to evaluate your argument if you include the whole argument in the question.

Comment: What does the rank-nul theorem proof for this look like? Daniel kind of makes it seem almost obvious.

Comment: Because the image of $T$ is $\mathbb{R}$ we have $\dim(V) = \dim(\ker(T)) + \dim(\text{im}(T)) = n+1$, so because the set $\{v,v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a linearly independent set of size $n+1$ it must be a basis for $V$.  However, I don't know if we need some assumption on finite-dimensionality of $V$ to use this proof.

Comment: If $V$ is not finite dimensional, how do you define $\dim V$?

Comment: As the cardinality of any basis of $V$.  But it occurs to me that one might have problems, because if $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal then $\kappa$ and $\kappa+1$ have the same size.  Perhaps you should ask Daniel to explain his mumblings.

Answer (score 0):

It is easiest to go for proving $V=\langle v\rangle\oplus \ker T$, as it will ten follow that *any* bases of $\langle v\rangle$ and of $\ker T$ will combine to one of$~V$ (one does not even need finite dimensionality for this). Now since $v\notin\ker T$ it is obvious that $\langle v\rangle\cap \ker T=\{0\}$. To see that $V=\langle v\rangle+\ker T$ write any $u\in V$ as $u=\alpha v+(u-\alpha v)$ where $\alpha=\frac{T(u)}{T(v)}$; check easily that this ensures $u-\alpha v\in\ker T$.

Answer (score 0):

The most general approach for this could probably be:

Let $\;V\;$ be a linear sapce over a field $\;\Bbb F\;$ , and let $\;f\;$ be a non-zero linear functional (i.e. , $\;0\neq f\in V^*\;$) , then

== $\;f\;$ is onto

== $\;\ker f\;$ is a proper maximal subspace of $\;V\;$ , meaning that

$$\forall\,x\in V\setminus\ker f\;,\;\;V=\text{span}\,\{\ker f\;,\;x\}$$

If $\;\dim V=n<\infty\;$ the above means $\;\dim\ker f=n-1\;$ and , in any case, $\;\ker f\;$ is called a hyperplane (or hyperspace) of $\;V\;$